# 'Must declare the scalar variable "@SKU".'

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I am using dapper to insert to a database, have been looking at my code to find what has happened, could not find anything out of the ordinary.

The code works with the SELECT statement, but not when I do an insert
I always get the error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable
>   "@SKU".

When I remove the first parameter from the database, the class, the function and the procedure, I always get the same error for the first parameter.

```
public class Products
{
    public string SKU;
    public string Title;
    public string ImageLink;
}
```

Using dapper function to insert:

```
public void insertItem(Products newProduct)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("SellersDB")))
    {
        List<Products> dbnewProduct = new List<Products>();
        dbnewProduct.Add(newProduct);

        connection.Execute("dbo.Item_Insert @SKU, @Title, @ImageLink", dbnewProduct);
    }
}
```

The procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Item_Insert]

@SKU nchar(10),
@Title nchar(100),
@ImageLink nchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

insert into dbo.ProductsTable (SKU, Title, ImageLink) values (@SKU, @Title, @ImageLink);

END
```

The database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductsTable] (

[SKU]       NCHAR (10)  NULL,
[Title]     NCHAR (100) NULL,
[ImageLink] NCHAR (50)  NULL
);
```

The error happened on the excite line.

Comment: The whole point of an ORM like dapper is that you dont need custom stored procedures. Example: https://dapper-tutorial.net/insert

Comment: @ADyson not necessarily, [Dapper fully supports stored procedures](https://dapper-tutorial.net/execute) and a lot of people prefer using it this way. Much easier to implement custom logic, validation, etc. with procedures.

Comment: i use it to organize the code and easily change things while developing.

Comment: @marcinJ...of course, I use them myself with entity Framework. But for a simple insert such as this there doesn't seem much need for a procedure, it's just an extra thing to maintain where all the fields to be inserted must be enumerated (twice). That was my point really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dapper wants properties, not fields; try:

```cs
public class Products
{
    public string SKU {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string ImageLink {get;set;}
}
```

and try again; you only need to pass the single object - you don't need a list here. You can *combine* this with the `CommandType.StoredProcedure` approach if you choose (as noted by MarcinJ) - but be careful that this exchanges *positional* parameter passing (in the original question) to *named* parameter passing - so be sure to check that this doesn't change the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The way to call a stored procedure with Dapper is:

```
connection.Execute("Item_Insert", dbnewProduct, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Also, you don't need a list, you can simply use `newProduct` there.

Comment: it did not work, i got:  'Procedure or function 'Item_Insert' expects parameter '@SKU', which was not supplied.'.

Comment: minor note: this changes from *positional* parameter passing (in the question) to *named* parameter passing. This might be fine, or it might change the meaning. Just something to be careful about.